# Google search via speech in c#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, google-search

I am making my own jarvis program and when I say "search for" + something I want to
open Google and search for "something". Here my code...( I don't paste it all)

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Cpyros\Desktop\lefteris\Commands.txt")))));
        _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
        _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
    void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        int ranNum = rnd.Next(1, 10);
        string speech = e.Result.Text;
        switch (speech)
        {
            //GREETINGS
            case "hello":
            case "hello jarvis":
                if (ranNum < 6) { JARVIS.Speak("Hello sir"); }
                else if (ranNum > 5) { JARVIS.Speak("Hi"); }
                break;
            case "goodbye":
            case "goodbye jarvis":
            case "close":
            case "close jarvis":
                JARVIS.Speak("Until next time");
                Close();
                break;
            case "jarvis":
                if (ranNum < 5) { QEvent = ""; JARVIS.Speak("Yes sir"); }
                else if (ranNum > 4) { QEvent = ""; JARVIS.Speak("Yes?"); }
                break;

            //WEBSITES
            case "open facebook":
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.facebook.com");
                break;
            case "open google":
                Process.Start("https://www.google.gr/?gws_rd=cr");
                JARVIS.Speak("Okay sir");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^%.");
                break;
        here i want to add a case like "search for" + the thing i want to search...
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Google has a query string that you can use to go right to a user input search string. Take the following for example:

> https://www.google.com/#q=test+and+such

(thanks to Matt R, I learned there is also `https://www.google.com/search?q=test+and+such`)

You can then use a modifiction of your previous Google case statement:

```
default:
    if (speech.Contains("search for")
    {
        Process.Start("https://www.google.com/#q=" + userInput);
        ...
```

You will have to make sure the `userInput` is URL Encoded first by doing

```
string userInput = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(input);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer!But when i say "search for facebook(for example)" it open google but it's not doing the search..

Comment: @xXjarvisXx, I have updated my answer. Your problem is that `search for facebook` is not the same as `search for`. Using a `Contains` should do the trick. However, as Matt says, you should make sure you are using `ToLower()` or similar, so that capital letters do not throw you off.

Comment: Thanks again for answer,but its not working :/,anyway i hope i will find the trick one day :P

Answer (score 1):

As the switch argument text won't match a case statement if it has search items after 'search for', you could put this as your `default` statement :

```
default:
    if (speech.ToLower().Contains("search for")) // See if the string contains the 'search for' string.
    {
         string query = speech.Replace("search for", ""); // Remove the 'search for' text.
         // Old code (does not make the text fully URL safe)
         // query = query.Replace(' ', '+'); 
         query = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query);
         string url = "https://www.google.com.au/search?q=" + query;
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: It is good that you are replacing spaces with `+`, but that is not the only illegal character that needs to be replaced. This is why I suggest `UrlEncode`

Comment: Come to think of it, yes, a URL encode would be much better. I'll update the answer.

Comment: thanks for answer,but its not doing the search, i say: "search for facebook" and its not doing the search at all,im newbie in c# :P

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because your "grammarbuild" does not recognize words that are not loaded into your "grammarbuild". (I think) I'm still trying this too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same source code. you must add the search for command in the default commands.txt and make sure that you do not have anything in the custom commands.cs pertaining to the phrase

Answer (score 0):

As Nikki O said before, this will not work since you don't have a words in your GrammarBuilder. You can simple load multiple grammar or just do:

```
default:
    if (speech.ToLower().Contains("search for")) // See if the string contains the 'search for' string.
    {
         var dictationGrammar= new DictationGrammar();
            sre.LoadGrammarAsync(dictationGrammar);
string url = "https://www.google.com.au/search?q=" + dictationGrammar;

     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);

    }
    break;
```

This will load your dictation text that is not in your default grammar. I didn't test this code but this should work.